# How to call telepony and its sub class methods in Android activity class

Tags: android

1. How do I use non public classes in Android like telephony, `android.telephony.CallManager` in my Android application?
2. How do I import this telephony packages in my activity class and make it allow to access its functionality?

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to call/send sms then you can use the Intent:
call:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phonenumber));
context.startActivity(i);
```

sms:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
i.putExtra("sms_body", "message");
i.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + phonenumber));
context.startActivity(i);
```

this was enough for me.
if it isn't enough for you, you can use the TelephonyManager.

read more at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

as you can see, it is public. its just not initiate as new `TelephonyManger();` but via  getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE).

you can always use reflection if you will need some private class.

Comment: thanks i pleased for getting your replay...,but i think you didn't get my question?